# How to redirect to another page on a single click in django 1.6.5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i m using django 1.6.5 and tried to create a website,  everything works good, except moving from one page to other pages in a single click.I googled a lot, but i couldn't solve it.

in urls.py

```
url(r'^contact/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html'),
        name='contact'),
```

in templates

```
href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact
```

but it doesn't work for me.
Can anyone help me?